# Wood treated with copper green for a vegetable garden

Tags: wood

I am planning to build an outdoor planter box to grow vegetables.  If I treat the redwood with Copper Green will the vegetables be safe to eat?

Comment: I would not use any wood coating or treatment that I would not be willing to drink.

Answer (score 1):

No. Here's the msds sheet: [MSDS](https://images.homedepot-static.com/catalog/pdfImages/38/381d1441-0e56-4421-83dd-dcfe62773ed5.pdf)

Among other things, the sheet says:

> Product Restrictions:
>   Do not use on any material other than wood. Should not be applied to food or feed surfaces. FOR EXTERIOR USE ONLY (See approved label on product)
>   Wood treated with Copper Naphthenate must not be used in construction of beehives.